# Why the capstan equation is exponential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, string

Does anybody knows any intuitive explanation about the reason that the [capstan equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation) is exponential and not, as expected, linear?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link gives the derivation. Can you clarify what exactly you are asking e.g. is there some aspect of the derivation that is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At any point, the friction force is *proportional* to the tension in the rope, and the friction force is the *rate of change* of the tension along the length of the rope.

That is the basic form of the equation for every exponential growth and decay situation:$$\frac{dy}{dx} = Ay$$ where $A$ is a constant.